# How to add sub-items to dropdown and link them to their parent items

Tags: php, html

I have this dropdown which is dynamically filled with links to Municipality pages on our websites. They are registered as custom posts in WordPress. This is the current form:

```
<form action="<? bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
    <select placeholder="Zoeken..." data-placeholder="Zoeken.." id="jzhz-gmz-input" onChange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" size="1">
        <option value="">Kies je gemeente...</option>
        <?php
            $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type' => array('gemeente'), 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC' );
            $posts = get_posts($args);
            foreach( $posts as $post ) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <br />
    </select>
</form>
```

In the last years, many villages in The Netherlands have been merged and/or had their names changed and formed new municipalities. Now we would like to link those in the dropdown, without creating a new municipality post for each small village. The dotted names in the list below should open the page belonging to the post of the parent municipality.

How should I add this in the code of this dropdown?

The new layout of the dropdown should look like this:

1. **Alblasserdam**

   - Kortland
2. **Dordrecht**
3. **Gorinchem**

   - Dalem
4. **Hardinxveld-Giessendam**

   - Boven-Hardinxveld
   - Giessendam - Neder-Hardinxveld
5. etc...

Comment: Your answer can't be answered right now as we don't have the information required to create the shown structure. If the information about villages and the associated municiality is somehow available in `get_posts($args)`, you could extract it from there. Basically what you need to do is first create an array of the municipalities and then push all villages into the array as children of the linked municipality. Then output the array with municipality as `<optgroup>` and village as `<option>`.

Comment: Hello SaschaM78, Thanks for your input! I didn't provide said information because I do not have it yet. I was thinking about how to get this done, but I can probably create arrays of the municipalities and the children using Avanced Custom Fields plugin. Then we'll only need to mix them together somehow and provide the dropdown field with the correct `<optgroup>` and `<option>` information.

Comment: If you can find out how to get a list of municipalities with their children (villages) and add this to your question, we can surely and easily find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want as [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup)

```
    <select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, that is the layout I want. But how can I inject them between the items of the dynamically filled dropdown? It is not a static list where I can just put these items in between them..

Comment: With select - option tag not possible. But you can write custom with as div or use orher element like bootstrap custom select option. Like this: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/dropdowns/#split-button-dropdowns
 you can edit elements.

Comment: Other way with select - option tag used : https://codepen.io/Paddle_/pen/LVLgVw try you can edit without html tags and you want to make the design you want.